# We couldn't be on time if you hadn't given us a ride

Tags: conditional-constructions

Is there a natural scenario for the following sentence?

> We **couldn't be** on time if you **hadn't given** us a ride.

Note that I'm not asking about "We couldn't have been on time if you hadn't given us a ride."

Comment: To me, the tenses don't make sense together.

Comment: If a stranger has driven you and your friends to a transport hub where you can take an express train to a place and arrive on time, could you say that sentence?

Comment: As far as I know, this would fit a situation when you are on time as you speak, while "We couldn't have been on time, if you hadn't..." would refer to a situation when you made it on time at some point in the past.

Comment: @brilliant Thank you. Kate seems to be British. What dialect of English do you speak natively?

Comment: @Apollyon - Sorry. I am not a native speaker of English, so I am not qualified to provide an answer. It's just that I once was also bothered by this question and a native English speaker (American) gave me this answer.

Comment: **We couldn't've or couldn't have been on time, if you hadn't given us a ride** etc, obviously. **I speak AmE and say the same exact thing as Kate**.

Comment: Thank you, but your sentence doesn't describe my scenario.

Comment: Oh  sure, you want to hear that it's ok because the way you wrote it is "American English" and you'd be wrong. All utterances from human beings are "natural".

Comment: Haven't you considered the scenario? A stranger has driven you and your friends to a transport hub where you can take an express train to a place and arrive on time,  Your setnece doesn't work in this context.

Comment: That's where you are completely wrong. It has to be: "couldn't have been on time", if you want to use "hadn't given us a ride".  Of course it works.

Comment: Actually, I asked the same question at https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/we-couldnt-be-on-time-if-you-hadnt-given-us-a-ride.3844847/#post-19649667. See Keith's reply. Mixed conditionals are possible in English, contrary to what some books claim.

Comment: He said "We wouldn't be on time if you hadn't given us a ride" i s okay. Note the lack of match between the two clauses.

Comment: Mixed conditionals require the word "if".

Comment: There is the "if" in those sentences, as well as the OP sentence. Haven't you seen it?

Comment: Apollyon - In that scenario, I would find it more natural to say something like "We'd have no chance of getting there on time if you hadn't given us a lift."

Comment: @KateBunting Well, I'd say: We would've had no chance etc.

Comment: @Apollyon Keith is wrong. Not only does "couldn't...hadn't..." work for this situation, it's normal. If you don't think it's clear, just rewrite the silly thing to make it clearer! Don't create bizarre sentences and ask if we understand them -- we rewrite vague and confusing sentences.

Comment: Which "couldn' ..." sentence are you referring to? I've mentioned two in that thread, one with "couldn't be on time" and the other with "couldn't arrive on time."